# Find value in javascript array of objects deeply nested with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, es6-modules

In an array of objects I need to find a `value` -- where `key` is `activity` : However the `activity` `key` can be deeply nested in the array like so:

```
const activityItems = [
    {
        name: 'Sunday',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Gym',
                activity: 'weights',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Monday',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'Track',
                activity: 'race',
            },
            {
                name: 'Work',
                activity: 'meeting',
            },
            {
                name: 'Swim',
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'Beach',
                        activity: 'scuba diving',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Pool',
                        activity: 'back stroke',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],    
    },
    {} ...
    {} ...
];
```

So I wrote a recursive algorithm to find out if a certain activity is in the array:

```
let match = false;
const findMatchRecursion = (activity, activityItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < activityItems.length; i += 1) {
        if (activityItems[i].activity === activity) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }

        if (activityItems[i].items) {
            findMatchRecursion(activity, activityItems[i].items);
        }
    }

    return match;
};
```

Is there an `ES6` way of determining if an activity exists in an array like this?

I tried something like this:

```
const findMatch(activity, activityItems) {
    let obj = activityItems.find(o => o.items.activity === activity);
    return obj;
}
```

But this won't work with deeply nested activities.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `some()` method and recursion to find if activity exists on any level and return true/false as result.

```js
const activityItems = [{"name":"Sunday","items":[{"name":"Gym","activity":"weights"}]},{"name":"Monday","items":[{"name":"Track","activity":"race"},{"name":"Work","activity":"meeting"},{"name":"Swim","items":[{"name":"Beach","activity":"scuba diving"},{"name":"Pool","activity":"back stroke"}]}]}]

let findDeep = function(data, activity) {
  return data.some(function(e) {
    if(e.activity == activity) return true;
    else if(e.items) return findDeep(e.items, activity)
  })
}

console.log(findDeep(activityItems, 'scuba diving'))
```

Answer (score 4):

While not as elegant as a recursive algorithm, you could **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** the array, which gives this:

```
[{"name":"Sunday","items":[{"name":"Gym","activity":"weights"}]},{"name":"Monday","items":[{"name":"Track","activity":"race"},{"name":"Work","activity":"meeting"},{"name":"Swim","items":[{"name":"Beach","activity":"scuba diving"},{"name":"Pool","activity":"back stroke"}]}]}]
```

You could then use a [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to search for the pattern:

```
`"activity":"${activity}"`
```

Complete function:

```
findMatch = (activity, activityItems) =>
  JSON.stringify(activityItems).includes(`"activity":"${activity}"`);
```

```js
const activityItems = [{
    name: 'Sunday',
    items: [{
      name: 'Gym',
      activity: 'weights',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Monday',
    items: [{
        name: 'Track',
        activity: 'race',
      },
      {
        name: 'Work',
        activity: 'meeting',
      },
      {
        name: 'Swim',
        items: [{
            name: 'Beach',
            activity: 'scuba diving',
          },
          {
            name: 'Pool',
            activity: 'back stroke',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
];

findMatch = (activity, activityItems) =>
  JSON.stringify(activityItems).includes(`"activity":"${activity}"`);

console.log(findMatch('scuba diving', activityItems)); //true
console.log(findMatch('dumpster diving', activityItems)); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your function could be improved by halting once a match is found via the recursive call. Also, you're both declaring `match` outside, as well as returning it. Probably better to just return.

```
const findMatchRecursion = (activity, activityItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < activityItems.length; i += 1) {
        if (activityItems[i].activity === activity) {
            return true;
        }

        if (activityItems[i].items && findMatchRecursion(activity, activityItems[i].items) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

There's no built in deep search, but you can use `.find` with a named function if you wish.

```
var result = !!activityItems.find(function fn(item) {
  return item.activity === "Gym" || (item.items && item.items.find(fn));
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this returns the top-most parent that contains the object searched for, not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

We now use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for simple data processing tasks like this. It's really good once you wrap your head around how to use it. Here is how one could answer your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (activity, input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.activity === activity
})(input);

const activityItems = [{"name":"Sunday","items":[{"name":"Gym","activity":"weights"}]},{"name":"Monday","items":[{"name":"Track","activity":"race"},{"name":"Work","activity":"meeting"},{"name":"Swim","items":[{"name":"Beach","activity":"scuba diving"},{"name":"Pool","activity":"back stroke"}]}]}]

console.log(find('scuba diving', activityItems));
// => { name: 'Beach', activity: 'scuba diving' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: Im trying to use this lib, but getting this error. could you please help check ?

"<a class='gotoLine' href='#45:33'>45:33</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'escalationId')"

JSFiddle to the code and data json

https://jsfiddle.net/ksgsharma/59hkdmjb/

Comment: link to JSFiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/ksgsharma/59hkdmjb/4/

Comment: @SharmaK sure, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/jLg3kpd6/

Comment: follow up question, from the attached jsfiddle data want to find all the elements that have "referenceField: true"

Comment: link to fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/ksgsharma/n3L1gcs7/4/

Comment: esentially the grand parent since "referenceField" is under "properties" which belongs to the actual element Im looking for.

Comment: would be very helpful if you could provide an example of how to search by both key and value (one example each) and get the grand parent. Thanks

Comment: Did you read through the readme? There are tons of examples there... I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Feel free to ask a new question here on stackoverflow on how to use object scan for your use case and I'll do my best to answer it

Comment: thanks @vincent I tried readme but could not figure out below, 

From the attached jsfiddle data want to find all the grand parent elements that have key as "referenceField"

https://jsfiddle.net/ksgsharma/n3L1gcs7/4

Comment: created a new question on stackoverflow. Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113456/search-nested-js-object-using-object-scan-lib-to-find-grand-parent-elements