# How to gather only specific data from remote JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a local group of about 50 computers running Open Hardware Monitor and outputting a JSON file to http://theirip:8085/data.json . I have renamed the texts on certain parts to respectively CPU, RAM, GPU, HDD. I'm trying to get stuff like a Value which is a child of a CPU Core 1 which is a child of Temperatures which is a child of CPU. But I just can't figure it out.

I have some other code that loads the json (which i can see in the console), copied from an example.

I need to modify this to fetch just the temperature values of each CPU, GPU. The % use of RAM and % use of the HDD.
This is where I am stuck as I can't figure out the specific ways to output only these parts of the JSON.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "Text": "Sensor",
    "Children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "Text": "DESKTOP-PEJT98F",
        "Children": [{
            "id": 2,
            "Text": "Lenovo 20EV0013MB",
            "Children": [],
            "Min": "",
            "Value": "",
            "Max": "",
            "ImageURL": "images_icon/mainboard.png"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "Text": "CPU",
            "Children": [{
                "id": 4,
                "Text": "Clocks",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "Text": "Bus Speed",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "100 MHz",
                    "Value": "100 MHz",
                    "Max": "100 MHz",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 6,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #1",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "500 MHz",
                    "Value": "600 MHz",
                    "Max": "2800 MHz",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 7,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #2",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "500 MHz",
                    "Value": "600 MHz",
                    "Max": "2800 MHz",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/clock.png"
            }, {
                "id": 8,
                "Text": "Temperatures",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 9,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #1",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "31,0 °C",
                    "Value": "33,0 °C",
                    "Max": "58,0 °C",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 10,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #2",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "32,0 °C",
                    "Value": "34,0 °C",
                    "Max": "63,0 °C",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 11,
                    "Text": "CPU Package",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "34,0 °C",
                    "Value": "37,0 °C",
                    "Max": "63,0 °C",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/temperature.png"
            }, {
                "id": 12,
                "Text": "Load",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 13,
                    "Text": "CPU Total",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,0 %",
                    "Value": "3,1 %",
                    "Max": "100,0 %",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 14,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #1",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,0 %",
                    "Value": "2,3 %",
                    "Max": "100,0 %",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 15,
                    "Text": "CPU Core #2",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,0 %",
                    "Value": "3,9 %",
                    "Max": "100,0 %",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/load.png"
            }, {
                "id": 16,
                "Text": "Powers",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 17,
                    "Text": "CPU Package",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "1,2 W",
                    "Value": "1,2 W",
                    "Max": "12,6 W",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 18,
                    "Text": "CPU Cores",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,2 W",
                    "Value": "0,2 W",
                    "Max": "10,9 W",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 19,
                    "Text": "CPU Graphics",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,0 W",
                    "Value": "0,0 W",
                    "Max": "0,3 W",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 20,
                    "Text": "CPU DRAM",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "0,8 W",
                    "Value": "0,9 W",
                    "Max": "2,1 W",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/power.png"
            }],
            "Min": "",
            "Value": "",
            "Max": "",
            "ImageURL": "images_icon/cpu.png"
        }, {
            "id": 21,
            "Text": "RAM",
            "Children": [{
                "id": 22,
                "Text": "Load",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 23,
                    "Text": "Memory",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "22,2 %",
                    "Value": "30,9 %",
                    "Max": "33,3 %",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/load.png"
            }, {
                "id": 24,
                "Text": "Data",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 25,
                    "Text": "Used Memory",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "1,7 GB",
                    "Value": "2,3 GB",
                    "Max": "2,5 GB",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }, {
                    "id": 26,
                    "Text": "Available Memory",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "5,0 GB",
                    "Value": "5,2 GB",
                    "Max": "5,8 GB",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/power.png"
            }],
            "Min": "",
            "Value": "",
            "Max": "",
            "ImageURL": "images_icon/ram.png"
        }, {
            "id": 27,
            "Text": "HDD",
            "Children": [{
                "id": 28,
                "Text": "Temperatures",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 29,
                    "Text": "Temperature",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "29,0 °C",
                    "Value": "30,0 °C",
                    "Max": "37,0 °C",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/temperature.png"
            }, {
                "id": 30,
                "Text": "Load",
                "Children": [{
                    "id": 31,
                    "Text": "Used Space",
                    "Children": [],
                    "Min": "60,6 %",
                    "Value": "60,6 %",
                    "Max": "60,6 %",
                    "ImageURL": "images/transparent.png"
                }],
                "Min": "",
                "Value": "",
                "Max": "",
                "ImageURL": "images_icon/load.png"
            }],
            "Min": "",
            "Value": "",
            "Max": "",
            "ImageURL": "images_icon/hdd.png"
        }],
        "Min": "",
        "Value": "",
        "Max": "",
        "ImageURL": "images_icon/computer.png"
    }],
    "Min": "Min",
    "Value": "Value",
    "Max": "Max",
    "ImageURL": ""
}
```

Script in header (from an example):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#retrieve-resources").click(function() {
    var displayResources = $("#display-resources");

    displayResources.text("Loading data from JSON source...");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://exampleIPhere:8085/data.json",  
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        var output =
          "<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Provider</th><th>URL</th></thead><tbody>";
        for (var i in result) {
          output +=
            "<tr><td>" +
            result[i].name +
            "</td><td>" +
            result[i].provider +
            "</td><td>" +
            result[i].url +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        output += "</tbody></table>";

        displayResources.html(output);
        $("table").addClass("table");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="display-resources">
<p>jQuery example using <a href="http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/">jQuery.ajax()</a> to retrieve a list of JavaScript Training Resources.</p>
 </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" id="retrieve-resources">Retrieve List</a>
```

Any push in the right direction is massively appreciated!

Comment: What does that code have to do with this JSON? It's for printing the values from a simple array of objects. Your JSON is nested objects, you need a recursive function to go through all the levels. You then need to test whether the `.text` property matches what you want to print.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329392/find-value-in-javascript-array-of-objects-deeply-nested-with-es6 for how to search hierarchical data for specific values.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the code is an example I found online that works to fetch the json from a client machine. The part I'm asking help with is exactly what you are describing, modifying the output to loop through the nested results to get only certain json parts.

Comment: You're supposed to post the code you wrote that tries to solve the problem, not random code you found on the Internet that has little to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tricky part of this question is traversing the JSON. When working with JSON files I often find it helpful to paste the sample output into a site like this to make it more readable:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/

In this particular example, you might not need to even iterate over the results if each computer is only outputting a JSON file as you've pasted above.

```
console.log(obj.Children[0].Children[1].Children[0].Children[1].Text);
```

However, the previous poster is correct about iterating through the results if there are multiple. I notice you're using jQuery in your sample code. You'd do something like this in that example:

```
obj = JSONResult; // your JSON
$.each(obj, function(index, element) {
});
```

Comment: Great stuff, this explained a lot! Thank you much!

Comment: My pleasure! So glad it was useful!