# Find out if an object already exists in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to do a database operation only if my barcode is new to the structure.

My plan was either to use the function includes() or simply count the existence in the array.

I have found quite helpful code snippets like countDuplicate and the function include() to do the job but I guess my case is a little bit more specific.

But I not only have an object/array which consists of strings. (1st example)

I have an object which includes different objects and their properties.

```
//1st example (this works pretty well)

function countDuplicate(array, elem) { //just the special type of syntax for Vue/Node.js
    return array.filter(item => item == elem).length;
}

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW"];
console.log(countDuplicate(cars, "BMW"); //will return 3
console.log(cars.includes("BMW")); //will return true
```

But as I said I have more a structure like that:

```
var object = {
  sub_object1: { title: "test1", barcode: "0928546725" },
  sub_object2: { title: "test2", barcode: "7340845435" },
};
```

How can I get the same results there?

My plan was to do it like that:

```
if(countDuplicate(object, "0928546725") == 0)
    //... do my operations
```

But this not work because I don't really understand how I get into the structure of my objects. I experimented with different loops but nothing actually worked.

This is my array:

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
              items: [ //Barcodes
              ],
              status: 1,
              rent_time: Date.now()
              },
           submit: false,
           empty: false,
  }
 },
```

**____________________________________________________________________** 
**Solutions:**

I tried the following from @adiga and it works for the example but not for my real case.

This is a screen of my console:
 [image: This is a screen of my console:]

So

> A simple object.filter(a => a.barcode == elem) should work - @adiga

Like that?

```
countDuplicateBarcodes: function(obj, elem) {
    //return Object.values(obj).filter(a => a.barcode == elem).length;
    return obj.filter(a => a.barcode == elem).length;
}
```

Doesn't work anymore...

Comment: I am not sure you are wording your question in a manner that will give you the best answer. It sounds to me as if you just want to check if the value you have is already in a set of objects. Counting duplicates would only be useful AFTER you added by mistake an already existing barcode, no?

Comment: If you just want to find if the value already exists, then here is a duplicate for finding a value anywhere in a nested object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329392/find-value-in-javascript-array-of-objects-deeply-nested-with-es6

Comment: @mplungjan you can mark it as a duplicate. Check OP's answer

Comment: Please show an ACTUAL example of your array.

Comment: I don't agree. I have looked up some stuff for few hours before asking here. But it just doesn't helped me. I mentioned the other posts. I really don't get why you guys constantly want to close every post which is to some extent similar with other questions.

Comment: Okay @mplungjan, its above the "Solutions".

Comment: Are you calling it as `countDuplicateBarcodes(form.items,newBarCode)` ? and we want to close them because they add to the noise - especially when not clearly written as was the case with yours until after an hour of requesting details from you

Comment: I renamed the function to countDuplicateBarcode() and I call the Array by "this.form.items". At the beginning of my question I just want to keep everything simple and clear. Sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find value in javascript array of objects deeply nested with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329392/find-value-in-javascript-array-of-objects-deeply-nested-with-es6)

Answer (score 2):

Get all the values of object in an array using[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then use `filter`

```js
function countDuplicateBarcodes(obj, elem) {
    return Object.values(obj).filter(a => a.barcode == elem).length;
}

const object = {
  sub_object1: { title: "test1", barcode: "0928546725" },
  sub_object2: { title: "test2", barcode: "7340845435" },
  sub_object3: { title: "test3", barcode: "0928546725" }
};

console.log(countDuplicateBarcodes(object, "0928546725"))
```

Comment: I think OP wants to see if a barcode already exists before adding it

Comment: @mplungjan As mentioned in the question, they'll be using it like this: `if(countDuplicateBarcodes(object, "0928546725") == 0)`. The name should probably be `checkIfBarcodeExists`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find a barcode in your object, then your question is a duplicate of for example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330189/295783

Changed to match you requirement:

```js
const barcodes = {
  sub_object1: { title: "test1", barcode: "0928546725" },
  sub_object2: { title: "test2", barcode: "7340845435" },
};

const findMatch = (barcode, barcodes) => JSON.stringify(barcodes).includes(`"barcode":"${barcode}"`);

console.log(
  findMatch("0928546725",barcodes)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears like you actually use an array of objects and not a nested object. If that's the case, something like this should work:

```js
let scannedTools = [
  {barcode: "ABC", createdAt: "today"},
  {barcode: "XYZ", createdAt: "123"}
];

function isAlreadyScanned(tool) {
  return scannedTools.filter(t => t.barcode == tool.barcode ).length > 0
}

console.log(isAlreadyScanned({barcode: "ABC"}));
console.log(isAlreadyScanned({barcode: "ETRASDASD"}));
console.log(isAlreadyScanned({barcode: "XYZ"}));
```