# Search nested JS object using object-scan lib to find grand parent elements

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, search, nested

Using Object-Scan JS lib, want to find all the grand parent elements that have key "referenceField". Any help is much appreciated.

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ksgsharma/n3L1gcs7/6/)

```js
const find = (item, input) => objectScan(['**'], {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'parent',
    filterFn: ({
      key
    }) => key === item.key
  })(input);

console.log(find('referenceField', data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Object-scan was somehow not returning grand parent using `gparent` option, but based on the assumption that your properties will always have the same nesting, you can take help of `parents` option and change your code to this-

```
const find = (item, input) => objectScan([`**.${item}`], {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'parents'
})(input)[1];
```